# div starts behind a fixed header, instead of below header and is visible above header as user scrolls

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/zL7hzwpu/

`html` ..

```
<div id="playerView">
    <div id="header" class="parentWidth">
        <table class="childWidth">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <audio id="player" preload="auto" class="childWidth" controls></audio>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="left">
                        <img id="previousTrack" src="../images/previous-24.png" alt="Previous" />
                        <img id="stopTrack" src="../images/stop-24.png" alt="Stop" />
                        <img id="nextTrack" src="../images/next-24.png" alt="Next" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img id="repeatAll" src="../images/repeatAll-24.png" alt="RepeatAll" />
                        <img id="random" src="../images/random-24.png" alt="Random" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr/>
        <table class="parentWidth">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="search" type="text" class="childWidth" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Song 1
        <br/>Song 2
        <br/>Song 3
        <br/>Song 4
        <br/>Song 5
        <br/>Song 6
        <br/>Song 7
        <br/>Song 8
        <br/>Song 9
        <br/>Song 10
        <br/>Song 11
        <br/>Song 12
        <br/>Song 13
        <br/>Song 14
        <br/>Song 15
        <br/>Song 16
        <br/>Song 17
        <br/>Song 18
        <br/>Song 19
        <br/>Song 13
        <br/>Song 20
        <br/>Song 21
        <br/>Song 22
        <br/>Song 23
        <br/>Song 24
        <br/>Song 25
        <br/>Song 26
        <br/>Song 27
        <br/>Song 28
        <br/>Song 29
        <br/>Song 30
        <br/>Song 31
        <br/>Song 32
        <br/>Song 33
        <br/>Song 34
        <br/>Song 35
        <br/>Song 36
        <br/>Song 37
        <br/>Song 38
        <br/>Song 39
        <br/>Song 40
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

`css` ..

```
.childWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
.parentWidth {
    width: 98%;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
#header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
}
#content {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

- Issue 1. (before scroll) `#content` doesn't start below `#header`

[image: before scroll]

- Issue 2. (after scroll) `#content` is visible above `#header` as user scrolls down page. Ideally I'd like to still see white-space above `#header` as the `<audio>` element's `seek` duration remains visible.

[image: after scroll]

Comment: Just a side note, you should avoid using `table` for things other than displaying tabular data.

Comment: good point, i just find it easier to position elements with a table quicker then css sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish to make it smaller and have scroll controls only for #content you should edit your CSS lke this

```
#content {
   position: fixed;
   top: 120px;
   height: 70%;
   background-color: #aaa;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   width: 98%;
}
```

the height can be whateve you choose to set it. But in jeneral I will go with [Raphael Serota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053110/4471064)'s suggestion on this one.

Comment: this is actually quite nice, I hadn't thought about scroll bars only on `#content` element

Comment: be sure to check how to reproduce this in other browsers you will need to add -ms-overflow-style property.

Comment: this UI is specifically for a firefox addon, but good to know

Answer (score 1):

Elements with `position: fixed` are removed from the document flow, meaning they don't "take up space" on the page. Therefore, the next div appears underneath it, because nothing is forcing it down. Add `margin-top` to the div equal to the height of the fixed navbar, and it should look how you want it to.

To get the fixed header to display at exactly the top of your page, add `top:0` to it.

Comment: using `top:0;` on `#header` cuts the top off the duration indicator

Answer (score 1):

Use padding-top to the body of your page and give top: 0 to your header. As for the white space above, you could use a solid white border.

Css:

```
#header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid #fff;
}
body {
   padding-top: 120px
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud8y4175/1/)